# Calculus Made Easy Exercise 8 Question 6

Tags: calculus

Find the slope, at any given point, of the curve whose equation is $\frac{x^2}{3^2}+\frac{y^2}{2^2}=1$; and give the numerical value of the slope at the place where $x = 0$, and at that where $x = 1$.

Comment: I’ll help the reading if you use MathJax

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please [edit] your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck so that you receive responses that address the specific difficulties you are encountering.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Have you tried implicit differentiation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the curve, $\frac{x^2}{3^2}+\frac{y^2}{2^2}=1$, we have to use implicit differentiation to find the "slope" at a given point.

$$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{x^2}{3^2}+\frac{d}{dx}\frac{y^2}{2^2}=\frac{d}{dx}1$$
$$\frac{18x}{81}+\frac{8y}{16}\frac{dy}{dx}=0$$
$$\frac{18x}{81}=-\frac{8y}{16}\frac{dy}{dx}$$
$$\frac{\frac{18x}{81}}{-\frac{8y}{16}}=\frac{dy}{dx}$$
$$-\frac{288x}{648y}=\frac{dy}{dx}$$
$$-\frac{4x}{9y}=f'(x)$$

Now you just have to plug in the values to find the derivative at a given point